# Reloading only one DIV when checking a checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html, checkbox, reload

I have been trying to get a script to work, but no chance!

Basically, I want a Checkbox Form to submit automatically when a box is selected and then reload only one specific DIV (indexMain) on my site. What I am trying to achieve is to have a filter by Colors on the left, so when the user checks RED, only the RED items will be shown (by reloading the Items DIV).

This is my code so far (not working, since checking the colors boxes doesnt have any effect):

```
<script>
$(function() {
      $(".regularCheckbox").change(function() {
      console.log("changed...");
      var data = $(this).serialize();
      console.log(data);
      $("#indexMain").load("index.php?data="+data)
               })
    })
</script>
<div class="bgFilterTitles">
<h1 class="filterTitles">COLOR</h1>
</div><div class="colors">

<form id ="colors" method="post" action="index.php">

<?php
$colors = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT color_base1 FROM item_descr ORDER BY color_base1");
while ($colorBoxes = mysql_fetch_array($colors))
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' id='checkbox-1-1' class='regularCheckbox' name='color' value='".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."' /><font class='similarItemsText'>   ".$colorBoxes[color_base1]."</font><br />";
}
?>
```

Comment: what does the console say? I think you need to detect a click on the checkbox then determine whether checked or not before reacting

Comment: plus do not use mysql_query use mysqli or PDO, its not safe

Comment: the mysql part works just fine, it loads the checkbox options...
Console says: 
- Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.php:25

Comment: My point is your code will not be safe from SQL injection if you use things like mysql_query routinely

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Jquery submit a form via .submit() on AJAX success... how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675936/jquery-submit-a-form-via-submit-on-ajax-success-how)

The .load() function your 'calling' is really an event handler, so its not going to do anything in relation to submitting the form.

If your PHP returns and HTML fragment then you can use jquery (or standard DOM) to add the html fragment as innerHTML of your target div.

Update: too fast on my initial typing, the $(ele).load() function will indeed work, so check your request and response in Firebug or another developer tool.

Comment: .load() is not an event handler, it a method that loads data (eg HTML) from a URL into a DOM element.

Comment: This response didn't solve. .load() seems to bee the right thing to use... Any other suggestions?

Comment: Actually its both, although in this case I was too fast on the typing and short on the double checking.  Try .load(url, data)  instead of appending the data to the URL.  Also look at the request and response in Firebug (or Web Developer Tools) and see what things look like.

Comment: No effect. No reloading happens, everything stays the same when clicking on one of the checkboxes...